# Display output from multiple row to single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want select email address from multiple row to single row

Query:

```
SELECT p.email_addr||';' Email_Address
FROM pa_user_prfl p, pa_user_prfl_role r
WHERE p.user_name = r.user_name
   AND dmn_id = 'PGM-GRANGE CASTLE'
   AND role_id LIKE 'Site/Area%';
```

Comment: Answer :
helen.tumulty@pfizer.com;
Liz.Connolly@Pfizer.com;
Selena.Haughan@pfizer.com;
catherine.tormey@pfizer.com;

But I want like this 
helen.tumulty@pfizer.com;Liz.Connolly@Pfizer.com;Selena.Haughan@pfizer.com;catherine.tormey@pfizer.com;

Comment: you mean you don't want space between semicolon and next email id,use trim function.

Comment: @Harry: You should edit your question instead and show the current and desired results.

Comment: Who taught you this join syntax? It was used in the 1980s, but was then made redundant in 1992. Use explicit ANSI joins instead: `FROM pa_user_prfl p JOIN pa_user_prfl_role r ON p.user_name = r.user_name`.

Comment: You also maybe want to remove all of your co-workers email addresses from the post...

Answer (score 0):

You want to select a string containing all email addresses separated with a semicolon? Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this:

```
SELECT group_concat(p.email_addr separator ';') as Email_Addresses
FROM pa_user_prfl p
JOIN pa_user_prfl_role r ON p.user_name = r.user_name
WHERE dmn_id = 'PGM-GRANGE CASTLE'
AND role_id LIKE 'Site/Area%';
```